# Права администратора в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, root

Есть приложение на Qt, и обычно располагается в Program Files. В некоторых случаях, когда запускается программа, она запрашивает/не запрашивает права администратора. 
Что нужно дописать, чтобы запускался всегда с правами админа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Предлагаемый метод был проверен на Qt 5.8**

---

Чтобы программа запрашивала права администратора в Windows, нужно внедрить в неё файл манифеста. Файл внедряется в готовый исполняемый файл программой [mt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/mt-exe). Обычно она устанавливается вместе с Visual Studio. Если вы не используете Visual Studio, то вам придётся установить эту программу отдельно, читайте соответствующую документацию. Файл манифеста может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="applicationname" type="win32"></assemblyIdentity>
    <description>Description of application</description>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
       <requestedPrivileges>
          <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator">
          </requestedExecutionLevel>
       </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Сохраните этот файл под именем manifest.xml рядом с вашим исполняемым файлом. После этого запустите в командной строке:

```
mt -manifest manifest.xml -outputresource:your_program.exe
```

Чтобы манифест автоматически внедрялся в файл при сборке проекта в Qt Creator, нужно добавить в pro-файл сценарий пост-линковки:

```
win32 {
   QMAKE_POST_LINK += mt -manifest $$PWD/manifest.xml -outputresource:$$OUT_PWD/$$TARGET".exe" $$escape_expand(\n\t)
}
```

Здесь конструкция `$$OUT_PWD/$$TARGET".exe"` задаёт путь к файлу, в который нужно внедрить манифест. Если у вас файл компилируется в другое место, вам нужно откорректировать эту конструкцию.

Узнать, чему в данный момент равно `$$PWD` и `$$OUT_PWD` можно, написав в `.pro`-файле следующее и выполнив qmake:

```
message($$PWD)
message($$OUT_PWD)
```

Comment: У меня не работает ваш сценарий пост-линковки. Вы не против, если я добавлю тот, что у меня заработал?

Comment: @Стас, добавьте отдельным ответом и укажите версию Qt.

Comment: @Стас, было какое-то сообщение об ошибке? Или просто не собралось?

Comment: У меня исполняемый файл по умолчанию генерируется по пути: `$$OUT_PWD/release/{$$TARGET}.exe` (или соответственно `...debug...`). А по вашему пути я получаю `/path/to/out/folder/programm_name.exe` и конечно самого исполняемого файла там нет. И так как, такой, как у меня путь сборки - это настройки QT по умолчанию, думаю, что так будет у многих. Можно изменить путь и опираться на него (с помощью переменной `DESTDIR`), но далеко не все так делают.  Сообщений об ошибке не было, просто `MakeFileError` и код 1